# New to python: query re string of length when it’s made up of repeated copies

Tags: python

I am a bit stuck, not sure what I’ve done wrong in my code as I am given what an output should be however I cannot get to it:

Write a function that takes two integers x and y, but this time produces a string of length y made up of repeated copies of x.

```
def repeat_int_length(x, y):
    f = str(len('y') * x)
    return f
repeat_int_length(10, 4)
```

The output I get is 10, but the instruction said it should have been 1010.

Comment: `len('y')` is simply the constant 1.  It has absolutely nothing to do with your variable named `y`.  (There's no reason for any use of `len()` in your program, anyway - you're *producing* a specified length, not measuring the length of anything.)

Comment: Please use appropriate names for the parameters in your function. Which of `x` of `y` is being repeated and which one determines the number of times to repeat?

Comment: IIUC, `return (str(x)*(y//len(str(x))+1))[:y]`?

Comment: `f = str(x) * y` `f = f[:y]`

Comment: @not_speshal try x=100, y=5

Comment: What does the instruction say when `y` is not a multiple of the length of `x`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def repeat_int_length(x, y):
    f = str(x) * y
    return f[:y]
print(repeat_int_length(10, 4))
```

output

```
1010
```

It's called string slicing. It'll return a range of characters from a string. 
syntax :string[start,end,step]
So in this case `f[:y]`, characters starting from 0th index to yth index will be return.
If it's negative integer and you dont want `-` to be store : use `abs()`

```
def repeat_int_length(x, y):
    f = str(abs(x)) * y
    return f[:y]
print(repeat_int_length(-10, 5))
```

Output:

```
10101
```

Comment: you can reduce memory footprint by `f = str(x) * math.ceil(y / len(str(x))`

Comment: Thank you - I've just run it and it works!  I was missing the 'f[:y] bit. Could you explain what it does to y?

Comment: @new_compsc_student I wrote a small explanation. If you want more, you can google string slicing.

Comment: This is very useful, I’m still playing around with it and inputting new conditions. Let’s say x was a negative number and I wanted to only see repeated digits (with no minus sign) retuned, would I need to insert an IF clause that would multiply str(x) by (-1)? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @new_compsc_student  if you don't want `-` to be store, you can use `abs()` function which returns absolute value.

Comment: `f = str(abs(x)) * y` . for example, `(-3, 4)` will return 3333.

Comment: @sittsering I've tried abs() function before, but when I run it I get a weird output, for example when I ran (-3, 4) with the abs() function I get -3-3.....

Comment: @new_compsc_student check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have misunderstood the assignment.

> ...produces a string of length y

**y** here is an integer and it is the final length of the string that you will return. You do **NOT** have to calculate the **length** of the character **y**. **y**, the length, has been already passed as an argument.

Now for your task, this code shall work:

```py
def repeat_int_length(x, y):
    return (str(x) * y)[:y]
```

it will output:

```
1010
```

Comment: No, I did not hard code the 4, it was a mistake. Here, I fixed it. Thank you for pointing it out.
Moreover, No, it is not the same answer. Here I am trying to give OP an explanation on why his understanding of the assignment went wrong.

Comment: I believe this should be correct, but OP never said what happens when `y` is not a multiple of the duplicated string length

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeat_int_length(x, y):
    x=str(x)
    s=str(x)
    q,r = divmod(y,len(s))
    return s*q+x[:r]
print( repeat_int_length(10, 9))
```

You have to find out how many times you want to multiply your string.

Comment: Try `repeat_int_length(10,9)`

Comment: you can't create 2 digit length string with odd length thus the answer is 4*("10")

Comment: But this doesn't match the instruction which says "_produces a string of length y..._"

Comment: @user13966865 - You can stop repeating when you hit the target length. i.e. 101010101

Comment: Check your answer. Both `x` and `s` hold the same string.

Answer (score 0):

Try repeating `str(x)` `y//len(str(x))+1` number of times and return only the first `y` characters.

```
def repeat_int_length(x, y):
    return (str(x)*(y//len(str(x))+1))[:y]
```

- `y//len(str(x))` gives you how many times the total length `y` is divisible by the length of `x`.
- Add one in case they are not perfectly divisible.
- Return only the first `y` characters of the result using `[:y]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the instructions correctly...

```
def repeat_int_length(x, y):
    f= ""
    while len(f) < y:
      f = f + str(x)
    return f
repeat_int_length(10, 4)
```

Without knowing the other inputs, its tough to say....

With repeat_int_length(10, 4) you get 1010

However, what about weird cases where you get longer inputs:
repeat_int_length(101, 4) = 101101, if you strictly need to provide y length, then you would need to trim that answer(assuming they meant to keep the first part only):

```
def repeat_int_length(x, y):
    f= ""
    while len(f) < y:
      f = f + str(x)
    return f[:y]
repeat_int_length(101, 4)
```

Also, x doesn't need to be an integer, it can be a string, for example:
`repeat_int_length("Hello", 10) --> HelloHello`